# CodeIgniter limiting the amount of logins

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm going to try and do my best to explain this, because I'm not really sure if I fully understand what is going on.

I've built a codeigniter application where the user has to login. The login has been working for the past three weeks and I have not touched it since. Today after successfully login in a few times under the admin user I suddenly cannot login using that particular account, although I can with other accounts.

I have since torn apart my code trying to figure out what is going on. It seems the login process is working, but then after the sessions are set it drops them and the user is no longer logged in.

My question is, is there a set amount of times the sessions can be set on a certain user or is this perhaps something to do with phpmyadmin settings? I'm at a loss here on just what to do, I have never had anything like this happen before and frankly it doesn't make any sense that it would only happen to one user.

This is the login check in my controller

```
function checkLogin(){
    //This function checks the login to make sure that the user is indeed entering the right email and password
    $salt = '******';
    $loginObject = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => md5($salt . $this->input->post('password'))
    );
    $login       = $this->users_model->checkUser($loginObject);

    if($login == true) {
        $currentUser = $login;
        $this->session->set_userdata('currentUser', $currentUser);
        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', true);
        $this->user = $this->session->userdata('currentUser');
        $type = $this->users_model->getUser($this->user->user_id);
        switch($type[0]->type) {
            case 1:
                redirect('/myStories/'.$this->user->pen_name);
                break;
            case 2:
                redirect('recent/');
                break;
            case 3:
                redirect('recent/');
                break;
            case 'banned':
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                redirect('banned/');
                break;
            case 'deactive': // deactivate
                redirect('home');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        redirect('home/errorPage');
    }
}
```

and this is what I have in my model

```
public function checkUser($loginObject)
{
    //This sets the email and the password from the loginObject and then gets the user
    $this->db->where('email', $loginObject['email']);
    $this->db->where('password', $loginObject['password']);
    $query = $this->db->get('user_tbl');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();   
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Like I said this works for every user except one and before an hour ago was working for that one too.

Comment: 1) Show your code 2) There is a little difference between PHP and Code Igniter Based Session Variables in CI envoirment.

Comment: What does phpMyAdmin have to do with Codeigniter? Are you referring to MySQL logins?

Comment: @noobie-php just posted my controller and model, sorry when I was writing it submitted it before I wanted it to.

Comment: @Dai I am using phpmyadmin for my sql database and I know I have had some trouble with their limits in the past so I was not sure if this was related as well.

Comment: @zazvorniki try replacing if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();   
    }else{
        return false;
    } with if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;   
    }else{
        return false;
    }

Comment: @noobie-php now no user can log in, that returns a blank page

Comment: from what i can see $query->row() is returning an object and in your if condition you are comparing Object== True!

Comment: i am referring to this part $login= $this->users_model->checkUser($loginObject);

    if($login == true). http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html tells $query->row(); return an object of row

Comment: @noobie-php I understand what you are referring to and I did make the change, but when I did so then no one could log in. I tried three different users and they all returned a blank page. Before, two of them logged in just fine, except for the third that dropped the session.

Comment: logically those two if are logging using same Algo that you mentioned in OP, should not log in.

Comment: @noobie-php They are valid emails and passwords thus they are loggin in. The third is also a valid email and password and I have been using it for the past three weeks (including earlier today), but suddenly it will not log in.

Comment: @zazvorniki: Have you tried to echo or var dump in your IF statement? If not try dumping Session Variables in there, somewhat like this print_r($_SESSION); it will show you all sessions, Including CI based and PHP based. And then kindly post your dump here.

Comment: @noobie-php I have dumped everything possible to try and figure out what is going on. In that if statement with that particular user how I first had it the user comes back fine and I'm getting all the information. It actually gets all the way to the redirect in the controller and then the session just drops for just that one user. For every other user everything work fine.

Comment: If you think it is not entering the IF statment and its redirecting then it means that your User may not be In DB. There is another option to force test if user exists in DB. Try Creating New Session Variables for your particular test cases from that i mean . use $_SESSION['email']= "SOme@email.com"; and any other required field that you need to validate

Comment: Another Option is you can just do if($login) means if $login exists enter your if statement.

Comment: @noobie-php It is in the DB, I have been using the user for the past three weeks...it just stopped working an hour ago. It is entering the if statement how I had it and returning variables, it then redirects the user and then looses them.

Comment: @noobie-php I don't believe this issue has to do with the if statement. I can remove the if statement and just return $query->row(); and the same happens. I get back the information and then redirect the user and loose the session.

Comment: did someone 'banned' your account? lol

Comment: @dispake I'm not sure I know what your talking about. Are you asking if the account I'm trying to log in with is banned? If so then no, if it was then I would get a message telling me so. Plus I'm the only one working on this, haha :)

Comment: Have you checked the controller you're redirecting to?  Perhaps the problem is there.  How do you know you're session is dropping?

Comment: @dispake I have checked everything I can think of. It's only happening for the one user so I know that controller is working for other users without any problems and I have tried redirecting to other controllers with the same result. I have also played around with changing what type of user they are in the database and no matter what kind of user it is I still come out with the same result.

Comment: @dispake I know it's dropping because I have placed a var_dump before redirecting and after. The results come back before redirecting, but come back null after...but again for only the one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was with the user. It seems all my code was fine, but something that was placed within the user bio in the database that was causing the session to drop. I had been playing with images within the biography of the user and had copied over a gif from google to see how it would look, apparently the -webkit tags "broke" the sessions.

```
<a id="irc_mil" style="font-family: Times; font-size: medium; text-align: center; border: 0px;" href="http://www.pixeljoint.com/pixelart/16196.htm"><img id="irc_mi" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #efefef 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #efefef 75%, #efefef), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #efefef 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #efefef 75%, #efefef); -webkit-background-size: 21px; background-size: 21px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.648438) 0px 5px 35px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.648438) 0px 5px 35px; margin-top: 230px; background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;" src="http://www.pixeljoint.com/files/icons/full/cat__r177950541.gif" alt="" width="23" height="33" /></a>
```

once removing the -webkit tags everything worked as it should. Thank you everyone for all your help! Now I have to go and prevent users from doing this!